# Can I dynamically generate label + input tags for each element in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the context of a react project, I want to generate radio buttons for each element in an array.

Here the tags I need to render dynamically each time:

```
  <input type="radio" name="debt-amount" id="3" value="3" required />
  <label for="3"></label>
```

1/ Inside my form tag, I first mapped through my array like this :

```
    data.slides.map( (item, Idx) => 
<input className={item.introline} key={Idx} type="radio" name="debt-amount" id={Idx} value={Idx} required />
<label for={Idx}><label />      
      )
```

It would log me errors in the console as I need to wrap all tags inside a parent tag.

2/ So I then tried wrapping **input** inside **label** :

```
data.slides.map( (item, Idx) => 
<label for={Idx}>
<input className={item.introline} key={Idx} type="radio" name="debt-amount" id={Idx} value={Idx} required />
<label />
                                                
  )
```

This time it generated my radio buttons, but I wasn't able to get them checked. Indeed, I added some styles in my css, and a small black dot (".") was supposed to appear inside a checked. But it didn't for some reason...

3/ When I manually render input+label, it does work, but I would have to add these each time an element is added to the array. That is not what I want.

_

Is there a way to dynamically render label+input for Each element inside my array (in a way that it just work) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use map function to dynamically render label input for each elements inside your array.

I think so this will helps for you as well.

```
data.slides.map(item, Idx) => (
<label key={Idx}>
<Input type="radio" name="radio-group" value={item} />
{item}
</label>
));
```